# How to set default styles in unordered lists in Material-UI React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, markdown, html-lists

I'm trying to replicate [a simple blog from markdown with Next.js and Material-UI](https://mui.com/getting-started/templates/blog/) but something is removing the default styles from the unordered lists.

List items (`li` HTML elements) have `list-style: none;` set and have no padding. Ordered lists look normal and have the default styles.

How it looks in the documentation's example:

[image]

What I get when I used the same content and markdown handling code:

[image]

The problem persists whether I use markdown content or `ul`/`ol`/`li` elements directly in JSX.

[In the documentation example, the code that reads markdown and transforms it](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/blog/Markdown.tsx) into React components doesn't seem to change the styling either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I had the following fragment of code in a component:

```
<GlobalStyles styles={{ ul: { margin: 0, padding: 0, listStyle: 'none' } }} />
```

That was overriding the default styling.

It was in a old component that I didn't need anymore.

Turns out, overriding global styles recklessly can cause headaches.